# How to connect Azure Managed Instance in Azure Linked service

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

I am trying to make the "Managed Instance" as destination in Azure Data Factory(copy data). But, I couldn't see any option to select "Managed Instance" in Linked service.

[image]

Here is the list of Azure supported data stores,

[image]

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services#dataset-type

I tried selecting "Azure SQL Database" and entered the managed instance credentials, obviously it didn't work. Is there a workaround for this?

Is there a way to make managed instance as my data store ?

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server hosted in a VM ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean SQL Server hosted in VM as Managed Instance. Yes. It is supported for copy Activity.

In the link you provided : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server , I am giving the snapshot of SQL Server.

[image: Sql Server supported in the Database Section]
Please refer to the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server

Comment: This is On-Premises Sql Server. I am talking about this [Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance)

Comment: To clarify, the screenshot you have showed is On-Premises Sql Server, but am talking about, [Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance) Azure service. Or am I missing something here ?

Comment: @Pரதீப் Sorry. I misunderstood your question. I will update it.

Comment: From the ServerEdition of Managed Instance mentioned https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance, it is Azure SQL. So, you can connect to it similar to Azure SQL, i think. Please give a try. `SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition')  SQL Azure`

Answer (score 0):

For connecting to Azure SQL Managed Instance, you can choose “SQL Server” as the Linked Service type and associate a [self-hosted Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) installed on a VM inside the VNet. Microsoft is planning to add Azure Managed Instance as an option in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good blog post that discusses how they work together:

[Azure SQL Managed Instances and Azure Data Factory: a walk-through](https://medium.com/@mauridb/azure-sql-managed-instances-and-azure-data-factory-a-walk-through-bfb93e79ac0c)